# get all ids out of a variable with html code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using nodejs and have a variable with stored html code. To manipulate the content, I would like to get all defined ids. I tried to use jquery, but I am not quite familiar with the framework. I tried something like this:

```
const { JSDOM } = require( "jsdom" );
const { window } = new JSDOM( "" );
const $ = require( "jquery" )( window );

let Ids = [];
$(myHtmlCode).find('*').each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });
```

The output looks like:
[
'id1',
'',
'',
'id2',
'',
'',
'',
'id3',
'',
'id4',
'',
''
]

Is there a better way to do that?

Would be happy for some help. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: You've used `Ids` and `IDs`. JavaScript identifiers are case-sensitive, they need to match. I assume this is just an error retyping the code for the question (copy and paste is generally best).

Answer (score 3):

Search only for elements that have an `id` attribute: `.find("[id]")`.

If you want to defend against elements with an `id` attribute that's empty (`<div id>` or `<div id="">`), you could add a check before `push`: `if (this.id) { IDs.push(this.id); }`, or you can do `.find("[id][id!='']")`.